# Can I change the CSS of a contained element when the parent is hovered?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

Using just CSS or SASS, is it possible to make one elements style change when its parent is hovered?

For example, I have text that has its color set to red. When it's containing div is hovered I want the color to become black. But I can't override the color of any other text in the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <span>Stuff</span>
  <span class="child">Some Text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent .child {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.parent:hover .child {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you have this situation, where you'd want to

```
<div>
    Some text
    <span>Some red text</span>
    Some text
</div>
```

You can change the red text with the following CSS:

```
div:hover span{
    color:#000;
}
```

**JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6FBk/**

If I misunderstood your question please reply and I'll edit my answer accordingly.